# Plot $u(x,t)$ for a string of length $10$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

> Consider a taut string of length $10$ with wave speed $c = 1$ (in suitable units),
>   with a fixed end at $x = −5$ and a free end at $x = 5$. The deflection of the
>   string is denoted $u(t, x)$ for $−5 \leq x\leq 5$. At $t = 0$, the string is stationary with
>   $u(0, x) = 0$ for $\lvert x\rvert > 1$, $u(0, x) = 2(1+x)$ for $−1 < x ≤ 0$, and $u(0, x) = 2(1−x)$
>   for $0 < x ≤ 1$. Determine the shape of the string at $t = 0, t = 2, t = 5,$
>   and $t = 10$, i.e. sketch graphs of $u(t, x)$ for $−5 ≤ x ≤ 5$ and $t\in \{0, 2, 5, 10\}$.

The general solution to the wave equation with zero initial velocity is $u(t,x)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x+t)+f(x-t))$, where $f(x)=u(0,x)$. The correct answers are shown below. I understand the graphs of $t=0,2,10$, the graph essentially splits in half and moves left and right (initially the the height is $2$). My question is how does the height of the graph go from $1$ at $t=2$ back to a height of $2$ at $t=5$? Should it not remain at $1$? I understand its shape though.

[image]

Comment: @EditPiAf: What do you mean by reflected with a change of sign? I'm supposed to do this question with only knowledge of d'Alembert's formula. Any idea how the graph for $t=5$ corresponds to $u(x,5)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x+5)+f(x-5))$?

Comment: At the fixed boundary (x=−5), the solution is reflected with a change of sign, which explains why it's zero at t=2. At the free boundary (x=5), the solution is reflected without change of sign, which explains why it doubles amplitude at t=2, and why the solution is zero for $t=10$. D'Alembert is valid in infinite space (far from the boundaries)